# Accessing XML data in R that is several layers embedded

Tags: r, xml

I'm working with a well-structured XML file. So far, I have successfully accessed elements of this dataset that are only one layer/subfield deep. However, now I need to access one type of data that is more deeply embedded within this data structure, and the expected method is not working...

Excerpt from the XML data; this is the "target" field that I need to access, where each node (i.e. drug) can have between 0 and N targets (I am arbitrarily setting N to 20 for now, since I'm not sure what this value is for the entire dataset):

```
<targets> --> 51st field in each node
    <target> --> there are a variable number of targets per drug
      <id>BE0000048</id> --> this is the value I want for each Target
      <name>Prothrombin</name>
      <organism>Human</organism>
      <actions>
        <action>inhibitor</action>
      </actions>
      <references>
        <articles>
          <article>
            <pubmed-id>10505536</pubmed-id>
            <citation>Turpie AG: Anticoagulants in acute coronary syndromes. 
    ...
```

I have determined that the main Target field that I need is Field 51 within each node's structure, thus the hardcoded value below. I would think that accessing the i'th node's id value within the j'th target within the node's Target field should have an index of [[i]][[51]][[j]][[1]] or [[i]][[51]][[j]][['id']]:

This is my code that isn't working as expected:

```
Target <- array(1:NumNodes, dim=c(1,NumNodes,MaxTargets))

for (i in 1:NumNodes){
   for (j in 1:MaxTargets){
      Target[i][j] <- Data[[i]][[51]][[j]][[1]]
   }
}
```

The behavior I'm seeing is that I can extend the subscripts out numerous levels on the command line, and never narrow the result any more than the following:

```
> Data[[1]][[51]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "BE0000048ProthrombinHumaninhibitor10505536Turpie AG: Anticoagulants...
```

It doesn't seem to matter how many subscripts I add; all of the fields in the Target subfield are always conjoined and don't seem to be able to be separated...

Confusingly, when I run my code, I get the following error message:

```
Error in Data[[i]][[51]][[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

... which doesn't seem to make sense, given that I am limiting i to the number of nodes, and that there is no error thrown for even the ridiculously long list of subscripts show above, when I query that phrase on the command line...

Thanks in advance for any insights you can provide.

Comment: try with the `xml2` package and using XPATH. If you provide a short reproductible example i can show an example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion, cderv; I will plan to check out the xml2 package and XPATH. I really appreciate your willingness to provide an example.

I am pasting what should be a functional subset of my XML file; however, now instead of the "targets" field being the 51st field, it is the sixth. Again, it is the targets --> target --> id value that I want to report for each target, with each node having a variable number of target values. My code follows the XML content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<drugbank xmlns="http://www.drugbank.ca" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.drugbank.ca http://www.drugbank.ca/docs/drugbank.xsd" version="5.0" exported-on="2017-07-06">
<drug type="biotech" created="2005-06-13" updated="2016-08-17">
  <drugbank-id primary="true">DB00001</drugbank-id>
  <drugbank-id>BTD00024</drugbank-id>
  <drugbank-id>BIOD00024</drugbank-id>
  <name>Lepirudin</name>
  <description>Lepirudin is identical to natural hirudin except for substitution of leucine for isoleucine at the N-terminal end of the molecule and the absence of a sulfate group on the tyrosine at position 63. It is produced via yeast cells. Bayer ceased the production of lepirudin (Refludan) effective May 31, 2012.</description>
  <targets>
    <target>
      <id>BE0000048</id>
      <name>Prothrombin</name>
      <organism>Human</organism>
      <actions>
        <action>inhibitor</action>
      </actions>
      <references>
        <articles>
          <article>
            <pubmed-id>10505536</pubmed-id>
            <citation>Turpie AG: Anticoagulants in acute coronary syndromes. Am J Cardiol. 1999 Sep 2;84(5A):2M-6M.</citation>
          </article>
          <article>
            <pubmed-id>10912644</pubmed-id>
            <citation>Warkentin TE: Venous thromboembolism in heparin-induced thrombocytopenia. Curr Opin Pulm Med. 2000 Jul;6(4):343-51.</citation>
          </article>
        </articles>  
      </references>
      <known-action>yes</known-action>
    </target>
   </targets>   
</drug>
</drugbank>
```

Now that I have significantly truncated the above file, my code is now giving an error message that any subscripts above Data[[1]][[1]] are out of bounds, but hopefully this code gives you an idea of what I'm aiming to do...

```
library(XML)

# Save the database file as a tree structure
xmldata = xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse("DrugBank_TruncatedDatabase_v4_Tiny.xml"))

# Number of nodes in the entire database file
NumNodes <- xmlSize(xmldata)

MaxTargets <- 20

Data <- xmlSApply(xmldata, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))

Target <- array(1:NumNodes, dim=c(1,NumNodes,MaxTargets))

for (i in 1:NumNodes){
   for (j in 1:MaxTargets){
      Target[i][j] <- Data[[i]][[5]][[j]][[1]]
   }
}
```

Thanks for your input!